# Upgrade Wordpress from 3.8 to 4.x latest (including Woocommerce and WPML), But Huge volume of data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, upgrade, wpml

### Here is my situation:

I have an eshop site with **Wordpress + Woocommerce + WPML** installed.  Since the Wordpress is old and I want to upgrade it to latest version.

However, the problem is that **the database size is 1.3GB**.

I've tried download everything (website files and DB), and do a trial upgrade on my own machine.  No doubt that after upgrading all the wordpress files, **it spent huge amount of time upgrading database, mainly by: Wordpress, Woocommerce and WPML (especially WPML)**, and **finally timeout and incompleted**.

And since WC and WPML are old also, when I upgrade them, it takes another huge amount of time upgrading DB, again: **timeout and incompleted**.

### Here is my question:

Can you please tell me, other than running the normal upgrade procedure, **are there any other way to upgrade everything (WP, plugins etc) which is DB-intensive, given that the data in DB is important and I don't want to remove/delete it??**

Thank you very much in advance for all your help.

Comment: Server timeout is mainly due to the server you are using wasn't able to handle the large amount of php data during the upgrade procedure, can be caused by low resources or CPU limit. I suggest you to contact your hosting provider (if you are hosting through 3rd party) and optimize your server to be more Wordpress friendly or upgrade to a better host.

Comment: Another remedy to your problem is download and upgrade your wordpress core and plugins manually through FTP rather than using WPML

Comment: You could try https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/

Comment: @Vincent1989 / Scuzzy Thank you for your advises.  I own the server but the server is, I think, optimized.  The problem is not uploading through FTP, I can do that.  But it is the post-upgrade procedure from WP/WC/WPML takes huge amount of time and at last, timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Try local dump to database. First upload it to server or download it on server then crate a new db and local dumb on it. I have around 500MB database and it takes 3 to 4 minutes to uploading to new database. It will take max 10 minutes for your 1.3 Gb Db.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't have problem download the whole DB or whole site, but I have problem of those post-update operation after updating all the files (WP/WC/WPML).  Downloading everything and handle it locally is a good idea, but the point is it still have timeout problem...  :D